# how to skip authentication on Zend external request

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, file-get-contents

I m building a mail parser script that will fetch content from a mail box
and send few  "update" requests to the a WebPage backend(on Zend_Framework).

The idea is to have the  mailChecker.php file stand alone and to call it with Cron Job.

All works good until I try call the update url:

```
file_get_content("http://mySite.com/update-item/id/1");
```

The framework redirects my request to the Login Form ...

What would be the cleanest way fix this?
I don't wont to edit too much the login functionality

Is there a way to skip the authentication check for specific request? 
(security is not a big issue here)

Or a easy way to create a session for my stand alone script before I call the updates:
file_get_content("http://mySite.com/easy-auth/admin/admin");

Looking for a simple / ugly solution, I don't wont to edit the current Authentication too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to authenticate as you normally do prior to calling the update url?  If there is a simple session based authentication, you could curl the login action passing login details and enabling cookie jar. And then curl again to get data from update script.

Another solution, if there are really NO security requirements, just disable authentication checks for incoming requests from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are after a quick and dirty solution, but this is poor design. Your cron job should run whatever code the update-item action runs (preferably without duplicating it). Making a web request to your own site slows down the cron jobs, adds unnecessary load on your server and causes problems exactly like the one you are experiencing now.

I would suggest moving the update item logic into a service class that the controller calls. You can then call the same method from your cron job. This is cleaner, faster, and easier to unit test.

Comment: true, but then the cron job will need to authenticate before accessing the a back-end controller (same problem).

Comment: IMO cron jobs should not access controller classes at all, so they don't need to worry about authentication. When I said move the item update item logic into a service class I meant only that logic - any authentication code would remain in the controller.

Comment: No, it is not possible. The updateItem() involves several object modification, validations, triggers, and the final DB update.